# Does the zeta potential of a nanoparticle generally take into account ligand charge?

Tags: biochemistry, pharmacology, biophysics, electrophysiology

For example, if I had a quantum dot nanoparticle with conjugated linker peptides capped with polyarginine tracts.

Would the localization of negative charge from arginine change the zeta potential of the overall np-peptide complex?

Or does the polyarginine tract have its own stationary layer and its own zeta potential separate from that of the QD? Especially if it extends outside the slipping plane of the QD?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In particular, this question doesn't seem to have a biological component — is there some reason you think this question belongs in Biology.SE? Thanks! 

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to have anything to do with biology.

Comment: Sorry I'm new and this is my first ever post.  How related to biology the question has to be? I suppose the question is more of a literal chemistry or physics question.  However, I posit that zeta potential is critical to how effectively nanoparticles and drug delivery systems interact with any biological model?

Comment: The links put in my first comment contain the official guidelines. I agree that chemistry or physics would seem more appropriate, but lack the background to suggest which would be more appropriate — I suggest searching for terms like "zeta potential" on both of those sites and see whether anything remotely similar to this turns up. If they do then try there. Good luck!